# Word for choosing the desire of a majority over a minority

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the act of prioritizing the wishes of a majority of some community over the wishes of a minority.

Before, I would use the word *chauvinism* for this purpose, but apparently the word chiefly refers to exaggerated or even bigoted patriotism or sexism. It also carries a strongly negative connotation, whereas I'm trying to put my finger on a milder term.

The phrase *peer pressure* doesn't hit the nail on the head either, as it implies that a person is bullied into doing something that many of his peers want him to do so that he would fit in with them. But what if his peers have no intention of forcing him to follow their example, and it's a governing body of some kind that merely ignores his unique request in favor of a more  popular request?

I also don't feel that the word *democracy* would fit, for the opposite reasons: it carries a strongly positive connotation, as a democratic decision implies that it is a decision that everybody wants or can agree with. But what word would imply that a certain decision is something that many people want and can benefit from, but would ignore or hurt a select few?

**Examples of what I mean:**
A local government decides to stop funding their town's art gallery due to low attendance rates, and re-allocates the money to a popular sports club instead. This would be discriminatory against art-lovers, however few they may be.

Or, the student council of the Computer Science faculty is trying to convince professors to focus more on web applications because most of the students that will graduate want jobs in web development. However, this would be of no value to the very small minority of students that want to work in embedded systems, and the student council ignores these students' request for a course in programming micro-controllers.

Comment: Perhaps some form of "populism"?

Comment: I disagree that *democracy* is wrong. That actually *is* [the definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/democracy): " : government by the people *especially* : rule of the majority."

Comment: +1 for democracy.

Comment: @Keepthesemind That comes close, but populism is often associated with catering to ordinary folk or "the masses" and is mostly used as a political term. Also, populists rarely fulfill their promises: like a politician pretending to care about fixing the roads in order to attract more votes for an election. I'm looking for a term where, say, a person fulfills a promise to the majority not out of popularity, but because they genuinely believe that it's more important than helping out individuals.

Comment: @JasonBassford I feel that democracy still wouldn't fit, because you can hardly accuse the student council from my above example of being "too democratic". That feels like a compliment. Even if the council believes it is acting democratically, it is actually discriminating against a minority. It is this discrimination against (or, at least, ignoring of) a minority, in favor of the majority, that I'm focusing on.

Comment: @ChrisW. In that case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority

Comment: @Keepthesemind Thank you! That's very close to what I mean, and by going down the rabbit hole of Wikipedia links, I've found the exact term I was looking for (as it turns out, it should have been fairly obvious),

Comment: It's essentially impossible to accommodate the wishes of *everybody*. Unless you encounter a truly unusual circumstance, *somebody* will disagree. The best you can do is agree with the majority. And, yes, that means ignoring or overruling the minority—because there is no other option. The fact that a smaller number of people are ignored is the *result* of a democratic decision. If you want a word for the specific fact of ignoring somebody, that's something different than the word for the process that results in it.

Comment: And the exact term you were looking for was... which?

Comment: I would say popularist, except that is apparently defined (in British) as "designed for the general public; non-specialist; non-intellectual." Therefore, I submit/suggest that you coin the term "majorist", as it does not have an official "definition" yet.

Comment: @Keepthesemind I've posted the answer below. I should have started my search with the word "Majority", I'll admit.

Comment: @RonKyle Majorism sounds much better than Majoritarianism. I wish that that was the real word coined for it.

Comment: @ChrisW. Good luck pronouncing that.

Comment: @Keepthesemind eh, it fits in well with an article I was writing about proposed changes to the curriculum of my university.

Comment: This isn't a single word, but in practice, at least in the US, people would use "popularity contest."

Answer (score 1):

[Majoritarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majoritarianism) was the word I was looking for, or Majority Rule: when a governing body places the priorities of the majority of some organization (or of the populace) over those of a minority.

Argumentum ad populum (or populism), or Tyranny of the Majority (as well as Mob Rule or Ochlocracy) could be potential reasons or results of Majoritarianism. However, Majoritarianism has the potential to be good or (unintentionally) bad, which is the exact kind of mild connotation that I needed.

Comment: Aaaaugh! As much as I want to fight it, I have to grudgingly accept that "Majoritarianism" would be the proper term for it, based on the word Majority. At first I was like, "The word isn't "majoritary", it's "majority", so "majorism" would be correct!" but that's really just not the case. :)

Comment: @RonKyle I wish it was! Calling somebody out for being a "Majorist" while in a friendly argument is definitely handier than calling them a Majoritarianist. I'd probably stutter and say "Major Aryanist" by mistake.